# Python: Convert String containing Multiple True / False / Parenthesis into a Boolean

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, boolean

I'm wondering how, in Python, I could convert strings like:

- "(True & False) | True"
- "((False | False) & (True | False)) & (False | True)"

To a boolean answer:

- True
- False

The bool() function doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) these expressions as they are valid Python

```
>>> eval("(True & False) | True")
True
>>> eval("((False | False) & (True | False)) & (False | True)")
False
```

Comment: Be careful with eval. It evaluates the expression before validity and should be used with caution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Comment: Thanks for the help @CoryKramer and @"Notice Me Senpai"!

Comment: If you have any doubt that a string that you're offering to `eval` might have unwanted characters in it, in your case, you can use the following code: `import re;s = "((False | False) & (True | False)) & (False | True)";if not re.sub(r'[\(\)\|&TrueFals ]*', '', s):eval(s)`. This strips out everything other than True, False, etc. If anything remains then the `eval` would not be executed.